# pulling multiple values from up to seven checkboxes in php

Tags: php, checkbox

Good evening, I'm working on a project that has a list of seven options a user may select.  I'm trying to get all of them to pull with a comma in between.  This is not pulling from a db, but from a php form.

```
<html> 
          <tr><td><font color=black>Select all Constituency Groups that apply:</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><b><hr size=0 color=silver noshade></b></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="1st Year Student" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]" id="ChkCon1" />&nbsp;1st Year Student</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="2nd Year Student" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]" id="ChkCon2" />&nbsp;2nd Year Student</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="4 Year College Professor" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]"  id="ChkCon3"/>&nbsp;4 Year College Professor</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="Adjunct Faculty" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]" id="ChkCon4" />&nbsp;Adjunct Faculty</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="Alumni/Graduate" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]"  id="ChkCon5"/>&nbsp;Alumni/Graduate</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="High School Teacher" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]" id="ChkCon6" />&nbsp;High School Teacher</font></td></tr>
          <tr><td><input value="Industry Representative" type="checkbox" name="chkCon[]" id="ChkCon7" />&nbsp;Industry Representative</font></td></tr>
        </table>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if i need to name them the same or not.  But here is the post

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['chkCon[]'])) {
    $ChkCon = $_REQUEST['chkCon[]'];
} else {
    $ChkCon = ""; 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just wondering why this isn't a Radio button collection as each option seems exclusive of the rest.

Comment: don't know.:), teacher set it up.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: yes it is, it gets quite aggravating but worth it to find your own answers..lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$chkCon = $_REQUEST['chkCon'];
$values = "";

for ($i=0;$i<count($chkCon);$i++) { 
    $values .= $chkCon[$i];
    if ($i<count($chkCon)-1) { 
         $values .= ",";
    }
}

echo $values;
```

Comment: giving me a syntax error on line  for ($i=0;$i<count($chkCon_;$i++) {  I am pretty sure it's because it needs a second ")"?

Comment: Thanks that did it, but one more question, is there a way to stop the last entry from having a comma after it?

Comment: I apologize for posting the code outright.  Had I known it was a homework assignment I would have just hinted to the solution.  I hope that you do attempt to come up with your own solution to this problem.